# I am getting java.lang.runtimeexception parcelable encountered ioexception writing serializable object

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, serializable

I am newbie to android and working on a demo app with two screens to pass a data from one to another activity, During this i am getting below exception,

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing
>   serializable object (name = one.tusk.stush.connect.Post)

**code**

```
  Intent intentPostDetail = new Intent(PostListItem.this.getContext(), NewPostDetailActivity.class);
                Post post = mPost;
                System.out.print("========MY POST IS======>" + mPost.toString());
                intentPostDetail.putExtra("Post", post);
                intentPostDetail.putExtra("flag", "post");
            mContext.startActivity(intentPostDetail);
```

**baseObject**

```
public class BaseObject {

    static DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

    public static Date getDateFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {

        String value = "";
        Date date = null;
        try {
            value = jsonObject.getString(key);
            date = dateFormatter.parse(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return date;

    }
    public static String getStringFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {

        String value = "";
        try {
            value = jsonObject.getString(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static int getIntFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {

        int value = 0;
        try {
            value = jsonObject.getInt(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static boolean getBooleanFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {

        boolean value = false;
        try {
            value = jsonObject.getBoolean(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static double getDoubleFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {

        double value = 0;
        try {
            value = jsonObject.getDouble(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return value;
    }



    public static JSONObject getJSONFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {

        JSONObject value = null;
        try {
            value = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return value;
    }
```

**Post**

```
public class Post extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String postTitle;
    public String postImagePath;
    public Date postDate;
    public ArrayList<String> postKeywords;
    public User postUser;
    public int postID;
    public int postLikesCount;
    public int postCommentsCount;
    public boolean likedThisPost;
    public boolean commentedThisPost;
    public boolean inAlbum;
    public String timeAgo;
    public int totalReviews;
    public String loginuserReviews;
    int rv_cnt;
    public double ratingcount;
    public JSONObject userObj;
    public int userId;

    String reviews;

    public Post(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        //Log.d("JSOn", jsonObject.toString());
        this.postID = getIntFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "postID");
        this.postImagePath = getStringFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "postImage");
        this.postTitle = getStringFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "postTitle");
        this.postDate = getDateFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "postDate");
        this.postUser = new User(getJSONFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "user"));
        this.postLikesCount = getIntFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "totalLikes");
        this.postCommentsCount = getIntFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "totalComments");
        this.timeAgo = getStringFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "timeAgo");
        this.commentedThisPost = getBooleanFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "isCommented");
//      userObj = getJSONFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "user");
        this.userId = getIntFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "userID");
        this.totalReviews = getIntFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "totalReview");
        this.ratingcount = getDoubleFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "ratingcount");


        int isLiked = getIntFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "isLiked");
        if (isLiked == 1) {
            this.likedThisPost = true;
        } else {
            this.likedThisPost = false;
        }

        int inAlbum = getIntFromJSONObject(jsonObject, "inAlbum");
        if (inAlbum == 1) {
            this.inAlbum = true;
        } else {
            this.inAlbum = false;
        }
    }

}
```

can anyone please help me to solve this.

Comment: put `Post` class in the question.

Comment: What is `Post` class?

Comment: @Ironman - Which class?

Comment: Ok i am posting "Post" object class

Comment: @Apurva - Yes i have posted my post object class..pls help me

Comment: @Ironman - i have posted ,Please help me

Comment: Maybe you're trying to modify `Post` class' content even after it's compiled and you're keeping `serialVersionUID` same and that causes error. Try removing `serialVersionUID` and let compiler create automatically, it might solve error.

Comment: @Apurva - Hello,I found the cause ,when i have added `
 
 public static JSONObject getJSONFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {
  
  JSONObject value = null;
  try {
   value = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  return value;
 }` in my base object i found this exception,

Comment: @Ironman - Hello,I found the cause ,when i have added `
 
 public static JSONObject getJSONFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {
  
  JSONObject value = null;
  try {
   value = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  return value;
 }` in my base object i found this exception,

Answer (score 0):

Implement `Serializable` on the Model Class `Post` . This will fix the error.

```
   public class Post implements Serializable {
```

Comment: Whats your `BaseObject` class ??

Comment: i have  posted in my question,please see

Comment: Hello,I found the cause ,when i have added `
 
 public static JSONObject getJSONFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {
  
  JSONObject value = null;
  try {
   value = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  return value;
 }` in my base object i found this exception,

Answer (score 0):

Make your BaseObject class also implements Serializable like this

```
public class BaseObject implements Serializable
{
}
```

If still issue is there then update your question with BaseObject class.

Comment: Hey,I have posted my baseobject ot my question..Please see,help me pls

Comment: Hello,I found the cause ,when i have added `
 
 public static JSONObject getJSONFromJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {
  
  JSONObject value = null;
  try {
   value = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  return value;
 }` in my base object i found this exception,